# Ninject.Extensions.Logging.nlog2 - How to?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, nlog, asp.net-mvc-3

Browsing the nuget library, i came across [Ninject.Extensions.Logging.nlog2](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Ninject.Extensions.Logging.nlog2).  Some googling and trying to figure things out, I can't seem to find how or why you would use this extension.

Is it advisable to use with MVC 3?

What exactly is the point?

How do you use it?

Comment: There seem a few people using it even in here: http://groups.google.com/group/ninject/search?group=ninject&q=nlog&qt_g=Search+this+group

Comment: @Taesung Shin - Well, considering the newest message is over a year old, and that Ninject, MVC, and various projects have grown significantly in that time... I'm looking for more recent information.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's really very simple; both NLog and log4net expect you to use singleton/static references to obtain logger instances:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

This is widely considered to be an anti-pattern, but even if you have no problem with it, it's still going against the grain if you're trying to implement dependency injection. In the case of NLog it's not even an `ILog` or `ILogger` interface like log4net, it's an actual class. That carries certain disadvantages such as the inability to create proxies, deferred loading, caching, etc.

What the Ninject.Extensions.Logging project does is first provide an abstract `ILogger` class with simple methods like `Info`, `Error`, etc., so you can inject it as a dependency and switch the logging framework if you want:

```
public class WidgetProvider
{
    private readonly ILogger log;

    public WidgetProvider(ILogger log)
    {
        this.log = log;
    }
}
```

This is how DI is supposed to work - a class never goes out to grab its own dependencies, instead they're supplied by the constructor or caller as above.  Assuming you've already integrated Ninject itself into your project, that's really *all* you have to do, there is no additional work.

As for what Ninject.Extensions.Logging.NLog2 does *specifically* - it just provides an implementation for Ninject.Extensions.Logging based on NLog2.  The base Logging library doesn't actually contain any implementations of `ILogger`, you have to plug in one of the specific libraries (NLog, NLog2, or log4net) in order to get it to work.

If you switch your DI library more often than you switch loggers then don't bother with it. But if you're like me and use Ninject in almost every project, then it's a nice way to decouple your code from any specific logging library.

Comment: Thanks, great answer.  The lack of even a basic description was what I found so confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use dependency injection via the constructor you can pass the ILoggerFactory interface.

This is how I did it.

```
using Ninject.Extensions.Logging;
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ILogger _log;

    public MyClass(ILoggerFactory logFactory)
    {
        _log = logFactory.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        _log.Info("Doing work!");
    }
}
```

Problem solved!

Hope this helps someone.